# how do I dynamically add link text to a href in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this javascript code. When it renders it shows quotes around the text of the link rather than just the text. What is the syntax to properly concatinate the link text? My quotes are messed up but I cannot figure it out.

```
var link = "<a id=\"myLink\" href=\"\" target=\"_blank\">\"" + text + "\"</a>";
```

Comment: because you have quotes inside the tags. remove them.

Comment: Sorry I'm not following. Can you copy my syntax and post an example illustrating it? Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you had extra quotes. You do not need to escape those around `+ text +`. The following should work:

```
var link = "<a id=\"myLink\" href=\"\" target=\"_blank\">" + text + "</a>";
```

I prefer single quotes:

```
var link = '<a id="myLink" href="" target="_blank">' + text + '</a>';
```

When using the `+` operator to concatenate a variable and a string, you just have to keep track of opening and closing quotes. It can get tricky!

Similar example:

```js
var str1 = "string";
var str2 = "This is how to concatenate a " + str1 + ".";
console.log(str2);
```

Comment: And if you use a modern browser, template literals are the way to go `var link = \`<a id="myLink" href="" target="_blank">${text}</a>\`;`

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! Those quotes always get me! I loved your single quote example so went with that one and it works fine. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks Jashua  - I will keep template literals in mind too - cool stuff!

Answer (score 2):

Do this

```
var link = "<a id=\"myLink\" href=\"\" target=\"_blank\">" + text + "</a>";
```

Do not escape the quote before '+ text +'

Answer (score 0):

Check this code :

```js
const text = 'My awesome link'
const link = "<a href='http://google.com' target='blank'>" + text + "</a>

console.log(link);
```